# MPI: load balancing algorithm (Master-Slave model)

Tags: algorithm, performance, mpi, load-balancing

I'm using MPI to parallelize a loop [0,**max**]. I want a master process (let's say process 0) to initially divide that loop into small sets of **n** tasks (n iterations) and then progressively affect a set of tasks to **x** slave processes whenever one finishes its previous work (previous set of task). In other words, I would like to implement a load balancing algorithm using MPI's blocking and/or non blocking Send/Receives but have no idea how I could proceed. Also, Is there a way to find the optimal size of one set of tasks (the n parameter) in function of "max" and "x" ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'll stick my neck out as no-one has answered you for 8 hours and say people don't tend to use MPI for load-balancing, just for splitting problems into known grids/layers. You will have to think of I/O needs, and also things like one, or more MPI nodes failing and hanging up your whole app.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, thanks for the reply. Well to be honest, I've found many articles, while doing research for my problem, about different load balancing approaches (work sharing, work stealing,...) using MPI to improve performance on distributed platforms (especially heterogenous ones) such as clusters. So I don't think that it's unusual to use the Message Passing Interface for load balancing.

Comment: I have no desire to argue, and, as far as I am concerned, everyone should use the tools that make them happy and that they can wield best. I'll just say my thinking is more along the lines of this article http://www.dursi.ca/hpc-is-dying-and-mpi-is-killing-it/

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found the following code from [here](http://www.hpc.cam.ac.uk/using-clusters/compiling-and-development/parallel-programming-mpi-example) which is basically a skeleton for dynamic load balancing based on MPI Master/Slave model, exactly what I was looking for. I still can't see how to divide optimally the initial work set though.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#define WORKTAG     1
#define DIETAG     2
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    int         myrank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);   /* initialize MPI */
    MPI_Comm_rank(
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,   /* always use this */
    &myrank);      /* process rank, 0 thru N-1 */
    if (myrank == 0) {
        master();
    } else {
        slave();
    }
    MPI_Finalize();       /* cleanup MPI */
}

master()
{
    int ntasks, rank, work;
    double       result;
    MPI_Status     status;
    MPI_Comm_size(
    MPI_COMM_WORLD,   /* always use this */
    &ntasks);          /* #processes in application */
/*
* Seed the slaves.
*/
    for (rank = 1; rank < ntasks; ++rank) {
        work = /* get_next_work_request */;
        MPI_Send(&work,         /* message buffer */
        1,              /* one data item */
        MPI_INT,        /* data item is an integer */
        rank,           /* destination process rank */
        WORKTAG,        /* user chosen message tag */
        MPI_COMM_WORLD);/* always use this */
    }

/*
* Receive a result from any slave and dispatch a new work
* request work requests have been exhausted.
*/
    work = /* get_next_work_request */;
    while (/* valid new work request */) {
        MPI_Recv(&result,       /* message buffer */
        1,              /* one data item */
        MPI_DOUBLE,     /* of type double real */
        MPI_ANY_SOURCE, /* receive from any sender */
        MPI_ANY_TAG,    /* any type of message */
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, /* always use this */
        &status);       /* received message info */
        MPI_Send(&work, 1, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE,
        WORKTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        work = /* get_next_work_request */;
    }
/*
* Receive results for outstanding work requests.
*/
    for (rank = 1; rank < ntasks; ++rank) {
        MPI_Recv(&result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
        MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
/*
* Tell all the slaves to exit.
*/
    for (rank = 1; rank < ntasks; ++rank) {
        MPI_Send(0, 0, MPI_INT, rank, DIETAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

slave()
{
    double              result;
    int                 work;
    MPI_Status          status;
    for (;;) {
        MPI_Recv(&work, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
/*
* Check the tag of the received message.
*/
        if (status.MPI_TAG == DIETAG) {
            return;
        }
        result = /* do the work */;
        MPI_Send(&result, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```